# Why "Invalid Content Type"

Tags: marketo

Trying to update a data field on a lead record in Marketo.  Using **C#**.  I send:

```
{"action":"updateOnly","input":[{"email":"dfranks@gmail.com","leadQuality":"Hot"}]}
```

And get back:

```
{"requestId":"d98e#14b2d7dd1f3","success":false,"errors":[{"code":"612","message":"Invalid Content Type"}]}
```

Why the Invalid Content type message?  The field `leadQuality` is legit.  The email address exists.  I've tried a number of different fields and always the same message.  Access token is good too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Content-Type` is a HTTP header. Usually, you set it to `application/json` for REST calls.

You should do this in the code where you generate the HTTP request or REST call.

I found `text/json` as `Content-Type` and `Accept` header value in [one of the marketo examples](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/authentication/). You might try one of the two choices.

Comment: Right on target response - solved the issue.  I set ContentType = "application/json" and Accept = "Application/json"

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things to check:

1. As @StephenKing mentioned, I would check that your Content-Type HTTP
       Header is set to "application/json".
2. I would also confirm that the custom field you created for "leadQuality"
       has a String data type.

[image]